# How to make app NOT support iPhone4 or iPhone4S

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

For managerial reasons we do not want to support iPhone4 or iPhone4S.

1. Is that possible?
2. What should we do? Just remove armv7 from 'Valid Architectures' ?
3. What will happen if downloading the new version from AppStore with a iPhone4 device?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: if you dont want to give support for iphone 4 then just give your app support to iOS 8.0. i am only talking about iphone 4

Comment: because iphone 4s has support of iOS 9.3 and iphone 4 has support of iOS 7 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)yes,It is possible

2)Change development target in general settings to 10.0.

3)After changing the development target , we cant download from  iphone 4     and 4s through app store

Comment: Note that this will mean users who have an iPhone 5 or newer but have not updated to iOS 10 will not be able to download the app either.